# Selenium WebDriver reliable tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I know that this question was asked many times before, but I still couldn't find a solution that works for me. When I run my tests with Selenium WebDriver most of the times they fail with "NoSuchElementException". I tried using Explicit and Implicit Waits but nothing seems to work. So, is there any other way besides using Waits in which I can make my tests more reliable?

I'm using selenium-java-2.31.0 with FirefoxDriver. Below are some samples of code I tried to make my tests more reliable:

```java
public void waitAndClickElement(WebDriver driver, final By selector) {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
        WebElement elementToClick = wait
                .until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(selector);
                    }

                });
        waitForElementVisible(driver, selector);
        elementToClick.click();
         }
```

..and this:

```java
public WebElement waitForElementPresent(WebDriver driver, final By selector){
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    WebElement elementToClick = wait
            .until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return driver.findElement(selector);
                }
            });
    return elementToClick;

    }
```

...and this:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
WebElement user_name = wait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*@id='userName']")));
```

...and this:

```java
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

...and finally one of the tests that I try to make more reliable:

```java
@Test
public void test1{
 waitAndClickElement(driver, By.xpath("//*[@id='linkLogIn']"));
        waitForElementPresent(driver, By.xpath("//*[@id='userName']")).sendKeys("name");
        waitForElementPresent(driver, By.xpath("//*[@id='inputEmail']")).sendKeys("email@gmail.com");
        waitForElementPresent(driver,By.xpath("//*[@id='resetPassword']")).click();
        assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//*[@id='moduleMain']")));
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: If you're searching for elements that have Id's why use xpath? It seems pretty cumbersome since you have "By.id()" as an option.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I also tried with "By.id()"(actually, this is what I use now)but still, no visible improvement.

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors present on the page? Also, are there any dynamically changed ids or paths in your application?

Comment: There are no JavaScript errors and no ids or paths that are changed dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Try below custom method. It works fine for me,

```
public boolean waitForElementToBePresent(By by, int waitInMilliSeconds) throws Exception
    {
        WebDriver driver = getDriver();
        int wait = waitInMilliSeconds;
        int iterations  = (wait/250);
        long startmilliSec = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            if((System.currentTimeMillis()-startmilliSec)>wait)
                return false;
            List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(by);
            if (elements != null && elements.size() > 0)
                return true;
            Thread.sleep(250);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Use it like,

```
waitForElementToBePresent(By.id("linkLogIn", 5000);
driver.findElement(By.id("linkLogIn")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver is perfectly stable if you handle exceptions properly.  The problem is that the methods of ExpectedConditions class don't handle the exceptions for you although *most people will reply to your question as if it does*.

You can try my method if you want.   This method returns in between 0 to 90 seconds, depending on the scenario. You may prefer to alter this method a little, but it should work.   The **important concepts** here are:

```
1. Use the new FluentWait class with the .ignoring method (or .ignoreAll() ).
2. Use findElement() BUT make sure you catch (and nicely handle) the possible   
    exceptions (that you are ignoring in the wait).
3. Use a loop to retry after exceptions but govern that by either time or
    # of tries.
```

And the code:

```
public WebElement getElementByLocator( final By locator ) {
  LOGGER.info( "Get element by locator: " + locator.toString() );  
  final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>( driver )
    .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .ignoring( NoSuchElementException.class ) 
    .ignoring( StaleElementReferenceException.class ) ;
  int tries = 0;
  boolean found = false;
  WebElement we = null;
  while ( (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < 91000 ) {
   LOGGER.info( "Searching for element. Try number " + (tries++) ); 
   try {
    we = wait.until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated( locator ) );
    found = true;
    break;
   } catch ( StaleElementReferenceException e ) {      
    LOGGER.info( "Stale element: \n" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
   } catch ( NoSuchElementException nse ) {      
    LOGGER.info( "No such element: \n" + nse.getMessage() + "\n");
   }
  }
  long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
  if ( found ) {
   LOGGER.info("Found element after waiting for " + totalTime + " mill." );
  } else {
   LOGGER.info( "Failed to find element after " + totalTime + " mill." );
  }
  return we;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run findElement, you will get an error when it's not found.  This occurs for one of three reasons:

**Your selector is wrong**

If the selector is wrong, the best thing to do debug until you get to that spot and pause test execution.  Then use the console to figure out the correct selector to find the element.

**The element isn't there**

You may notice in your first action that the element you're looking for isn't actually there.  In that case, find out why you're in that wrong state and fix it.  If you're expecting the element to not be there, [Here is a great C# example](http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2013/08/webdriver-iwebelementexists.html) on how to extend your IWebElement object to allow for a .Exists() method.

**The element is late**

Determining if the element is just late is easy.  Run the test normally once and then run in debug mode stepping over each step manually.  If your normal test run fails while your manual steps work, you know you found your issue.  Typically the issue is due to AJAX loads not occurring on page load.  In these instances, a good webdev will typically add some kind of spinner image that you can easily search for.  I created a helper method called WaitForPageLoad() that first waits till page load, then verifies that the spinner isn't present, then waits again for page load to complete.  You want 2 page load waits because a modal will spin then load while a new page load will load then spin.  Finally, the page is complete, your element will be present.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to catch element by element without all theses wait and wait.until?

simply like : `WebElement username = driver.findelement(By.id("userName"));`

Can you drop your html by the way ?

EDIT:

What i can suggest is :

```
protected void sleep(int i) {
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
}

@test
void test(){
driver.findElement(By.id("linkLogIn")).click(); sleep(6);
driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys("user"); sleep(1);
driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail")).sendKeys("mail@gmail.com"); sleep(1);
driver.findElement(By.id("resetPassword")).click(); sleep(10);
Assert.assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("moduleMain")));
}
```

Comment: It was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately I can't drop my html.

Comment: Ok so, have you catch some of your elements using this way or every element throws an exception ?

Comment: I managed to catch some of the elements this way. The problem is that the test can't be reliable if 3 times out of 5 it fails.

Comment: Do you use other test framework  with ? like Arquilian Drone. And did you try to get your elements by cssSelector ?

Comment: No, I don't use other frameworks. I also tried getting my elements with "By.cssSelector()".

Comment: So, i suppose that you have tried to put a sleeper after your driver.get(url) ? like this one `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: Maybe your have dependecies between your elements ? Because I had that probleme once. i wasn't able to find an element because i needed to click on a button wait the ajax refresh and catch the element i needed.

Comment: Yes, in the setUp() method I have such an implicit wait.

Comment: I have dependencies between elements, but ,for example if the first element I search for is a link that I have to click on in order to get another element, sometimes when I call waitAndClickElement()on the link element the test failes with "NoSuchElementException" because it can't find the second element(the one I expect to see when I click the link). In this case I wait for the second element to appear with waitForElementPresent,

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the same type of problem, while using WebDriver with C#. 
I can propose 2 different ways on how you can avoid(not completely, but minimize) NoSuchElementException in your tests:

1. First of all you should figure out how your application works - does it use a lot of Ajax and other asynch. requests/responses. Then you can use explicit wait for every element, which can not be located at once.
2. You can write your own implementation of WebElement class based on Selenium WebDriver WebElement class.
   Main idea - everytime you will use your webelement it will relocated - so you will not be worry about NoSuchElement or StaleElementException.

Answer (score -1):

Well your code tells me that you are only waiting until the element is present.

```
waitForElementPresent(driver, By.xpath("//*[@id='userName']")).sendKeys("name");
waitForElementPresent(driver, By.xpath("//*[@id='inputEmail']")).sendKeys("email@gmail.com");
```

It tells me nothing that you clicked the field, then using sendkeys to input the text.
How about adding click

```
 waitForElementPresent(driver, By.xpath("//*[@id='userName']"));
driver.findElement(by.id ="userName").click(); 
driver.findElement(by.id ="userName").sendKeys("name");
```

The problem is the mouse focus on webdriver, it need to be focused in appropriate field AFAIK